# Is my C# Calculation Right?

Tags: c#

So this is the Question below and was wondering if my code is right can you guys correct me if I'm wrong? thanks:

Gold card coupon rules:

- if the balance is less than $2500 the coupon is 3% of the balance
- if the balance is more than $2500 the coupon is 4% if their years is less than 2 years
- if the balance is more than $2500 the coupon is 5% if their years is 2 or more years

Code:

```
public class GoldCard : Card
{
    int year;

    GoldCard(string id, string name, double balance, int year)
        : base(id, name, balance)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get { return year; }
        set { year = value; }
    }

    public double CalcCouponValue()
    {
        double Rate = 0;
        if (balance < 2500)
        {
            Rate = 0.03 * balance;
        }
        else if (balance > 2500 && year < 2)
        {
            Rate = 0.04 * balance;
        }
        else if (balance > 2500 && year > 2)
        {
            Rate = 0.05 * balance;
        }

        return Rate;

    }
```

Comment: And what did your own testing/debugging tell you? Is it right?

Comment: you can remove all `balance > 2500`checks in the `else if`s Also: What if the balance is *exactly* 2500?

Comment: Don't use `double` for monetary calculations. Use `decimal`. This also requires a `m` suffix on literals, e.g. `0.03m`.

Comment: Your specification is a bit unclear concerning rounding.

Comment: @bitboink, if you read the text carefully, that part of the code is exactly as it was written in text. :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at [unit testing.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)

Using the test framework [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) you can then write tests like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class GoldCardTests
{
    [TestCase(2000, 1, 2000 * 0.03)]
    [TestCase(2500, 1, 2500 * 0.04)]
    [TestCase(2500, 2, 2500 * 0.05)]
    public void TestNameTest(double balance, int year, double expected)
    {
        var goldCard = new GoldCard("", "", balance, year);
        double calcCouponValue = goldCard.CalcCouponValue();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected,calcCouponValue);
    }
}
```

Using the above code you can test the GoldCard class in isolation and pass combinations of balance and year and test that the result is the expected. 
You can also test that there exceptions are thrown if year is negative could be such a case.
This is very similar to the rules you wrote down in your post here but with the benefit that the test remains and you will get an error if you change something in the future that breaks the rules. 
The tests does not pass so there are errors in your calculations (or in the tests)

```
public class GoldCard : Card
{
    public GoldCard(string id, string name, double balance, int year)
        : base(id, name, balance)
    {
        this.Year = year;
    }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public double CalcCouponValue()
    {
        double rate = 0;
        if (Balance < 2500)
        {
            rate = 0.03*Balance;
        }
        else if (Balance > 2500 && Year < 2)
        {
            rate = 0.04*Balance;
        }
        else if (Balance > 2500 && Year > 2)
        {
            rate = 0.05*Balance;
        }
        return rate;

    }
}

public class Card
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }

    protected Card(string id, string name, double balance)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to check if 'balance > 2500' because it is checked in first if statament.

```
public double CalcCouponValue()
{
    double Rate = 0;
    if (balance < 2500)
    {
        Rate = 0.03 * balance;
    }
    else if ( year < 2)
    {
        Rate = 0.04 * balance;
    }
    else if ( year >= 2)
    {
        Rate = 0.05 * balance;
    }

    return Rate;

}
```

Comment: Similarly, you don't need to check if year >= 2 because it is checked in the second if statement.

Answer (score 2):

You should not verify the correctness of your code using a random webforum.

You should verify the correctness of your code using (automated) tests (i.e. [unit tests](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/108976-c#-unit-testing-basics/)). That's what tests are for. With unit tests, what you basically do is, you define and verify the rules you mentioned in code (c#). You can then run these tests whenever you want and once you make changes to your code can always get immediate feedback whether it broke some of your existing functionality (i.e. existing rules).

Here is an example using the [NUnit test framework](http://www.nunit.org/):

```
[TestFixture]
public class GoldCardTests
{
    [Test]
    // balance, year, expected result
    [TestCase(2400, 0, 72)]
    [TestCase(2500, 0, 72)] // you did not define a rule for this case
    [TestCase(2600, 1, 104)] 
    // add more test cases so all rules are defined
    public void CalcCouponValue_should_calculate_correctly(double balance, double year, double expectedResult)
    {
         // arrange your test (sut == system under test)
         var sut = new GoldCard(null, null, balance, year);

         // act (execute the test)
         var actualResult = sut.CalcCouponValue();

         // assert (verify that what you get is what you want)
         Assert.That(actualResult, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

last one should be

```
else if (balance > 2500 && year >= 2)
{
    Rate = 0.05 * balance;
}
```

Or you would get 0 if your year would be exactly 2.

-update- this way it's according to your spec, HOWEVER, your spec does not mention when the amount is exactly 2500. It only talks about more or less that 2500.